# VLD extension over windows

Tags: php, iis

Can I run [VLD extension](http://derickrethans.nl/projects.html#vld) over IIS or Apache that works over windows? and how?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the VLD product description:

> This is an extension for advanced users and can not be used to un-encode PHP code that has been encoded with any encoder. If you can't make it work then this tool is not for you. If you are certain there is a bug, then please provide a patch (or a good bug report).

Because of the way how you asked, your question can be specifically answered:

No, you can't.